# SKEmitterNode being rendered behind all other nodes

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sprite-kit

I have an issue that i can't seem to solve.
This is my setup:

```
SKScene
->Background
->WorldNode
-->Character
-->Platforms
-->Smoke (SKEmitterNode)
```

I basically want the smoke to follow the character while leaving a trail behind.

This is the code I am using in the didMoveToView method:

```
[self addChild:[SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"background.png"]];
[self addChild:[self worldNode]];
[worldNode addChild:[self firstPlatform]];
character = [Character createNewCharacterAtPosition:[self firstPlatform]];
[worldNode addChild:character];
NString *smokePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"smokeParticle" ofType:@"sks"];
smoke = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:smokePath];
smoke.position = character.position;
smoke.zPosition = 100; // no matter what value i put here it doesn't get affected
[smoke setTargetNode:worldNode];
[worldNode addChild:smoke];
```

In the update method i am making the smoke follow the character using:

```
smoke.position = player.position;
```

Now if I remove `[smoke setTargetNode:worldNode`] the smoke is where is should be (behind the character and in front of the background) but the smoke is moving along with the character and is not making the desired trail effect.

I tried setting `[scene.view setIgnoresSiblingOrder:YES]` but it didn't fix the issue.

Any help is appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: Help yourself.  Nobody knows what fart is.  You are adding smoke to what?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of updating `SKEmiteNode` position just add `SKEmiteNode` to your character and define in which node particles will be emitted by setting your emitter `targetNode` property.

Change `world` to background or scene in which you that emitter to emit particles

```
smoke.targetNode = world
```

Also by defining this your `SKEmiteNode` will leave trail

Comment: That's what I initially did, but to simplify the code I am posting here I added it a child of the world node since Character is a subclass of SKSpriteNode. No matter whose child the emitter is as soon as I set its target node  to world or even character.scene it gets rendered behind all the other nodes.

Comment: @JadFeitrouni you can try create invisible node with your scene size and give it high zPosition. And then make targetNode = invisibleNode. If you whant to see your particles your targetNode should have higher zPosition than other nodes

Comment: For some reason your solution worked, what is weirder is that when i set the world node's zposition to 100 even without the invisible node it worked as well.
Anw am glad it's working now, update your answer so I can approve it and thanks again.